# Multiply a factor by the overlaps between two tables with date ranges

Tags: sql, database, oracle, intervals, oracle9i

I am using Oracle 9i and have two tables with overlapping intervals:

```
CREATE TABLE slowdown (startdate DATE, enddate DATE, factor NUMBER);
CREATE TABLE products (prod VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) NOT NULL, STARTDATE DATE, ENDDATE DATE); -- In my usage this table is actually the result of a query and has many more rows

INSERT INTO slowdown(startdate, enddate, factor) VALUES (TO_DATE('09-SEP-2012 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('28-SEP-2012 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), .70);
INSERT INTO slowdown(startdate, enddate, factor) VALUES (TO_DATE('23-MAR-2013 07:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('28-MAR-2013 19:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 0);
INSERT INTO slowdown(startdate, enddate, factor) VALUES (TO_DATE('28-MAR-2013 07:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('29-MAR-2013 07:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), .25);

INSERT INTO products(prod, startdate, enddate) VALUES ('LOT001', TO_DATE('01-FEB-2012 13:30:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('05-FEB-2012 01:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO products(prod, startdate, enddate) VALUES ('LOT001', TO_DATE('26-SEP-2012 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('30-SEP-2012 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO products(prod, startdate, enddate) VALUES ('LOT123', TO_DATE('20-MAR-2013 11:13:45', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_DATE('28-MAR-2013 19:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
```

As you can see, an interval in `products` may overlap with zero or more in `slowdown` or vice versa. Intervals reliably do not overlap within the same table.

For each overlap `xdays` between `products` and `slowdown`, I need to calculate `time_reduction` as `xdays * factor`.

```
prod     product_startdate   product_enddate     xdays   fctr   time_reduction
LOT001   01-FEB-2012 13:30   05-FEB-2012 01:00   0       NULL   0     
LOT001   26-SEP-2012 00:00   30-SEP-2012 00:00   2       0.7    1.4
LOT123   20-MAR-2012 11:13   28-MAR-2012 19:00   0.5     0.25   0.125
```

Is there an SQL statement which can produce this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
   p.prod, 
   p.startdate as product_startdate,
   p.enddate as product_enddate,
   nvl(least(p.enddate, s.enddate) - greatest(p.startdate, s.startdate), 0) as xdays,
   s.factor as fctr,   
   nvl(s.factor, 0) * nvl(least(p.enddate, s.enddate) - greatest(p.startdate, s.startdate), 0) 
      as time_reduction
from 
   products p
   left join slowdown s 
      on least(p.enddate, s.enddate) - greatest(p.startdate, s.startdate) > 0
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f09e7/1)

Comment: What an elegant, simple solution. I started on this with a recursive query in mind and was hoping something simpler existed.

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like:

```
select prod, startdate, enddate, factor, xdays, 
       xdays * nvl(factor, 1)  time_reduction
  from (select p.*, s.factor, 
               case 
                 when s.startdate is null
                 then
                   0
                 else
                   least(p.enddate, s.enddate) - greatest(s.startdate, p.startdate)
               end xdays
          from products p, slowdown s
         where s.startdate(+) <= p.enddate
           and s.enddate(+) >= p.startdate);
```

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6983b/1

Answer (score 0):

I'd write PL/SQL functions for each calculation and call them into my select to get the results you want. There might be a way to do this in SQL but it'll get a little ugly.